# AEM content search issue using com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.Search api

Tags: aem

I am developing a site using AEM 6.3 using Touch UI & Sighty.

I want to implement the tag based search functionality in our project which could search through the whole website using tags, also we want to have **Did You Mean** functionality.

For this, I used **com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.Search** api beacuse it helps me getting the result list as well as the did you mean result sets which fulfils all my requirements .

I did not use **Query Builder** api because it only provides us with the rigid result sets and does not fulfill the **Did You Mean** functionality.

The problem arises as soon as we start hitting the Site URLs from an anonymous user (i.e without logging into AEM ).
However, as soon as we give etc/tags permissions to an anonymous user it starts working fine .

But I don't wish to give permission to an anonymous user .

What will be the appropriate solution for this?

Is there any other/better approach for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `etc/tags` permissions are required for anonymous users in order for this feature to work. This is because the queries look at tags to work out the synonyms or 'Did you mean' logic.

> But I don't wish to give permission to an anonymous user

You are probably concerned about security over here. You can remedy this by:

- Give read-only permissions to anonymous users
- Block the /etc/tags on your dispatcher (or equivalent layer) so that it cannot be accessed from the anonymous users.

The anonymous user permissions are required only to make the queries do the filtering properly. This does not mean that you need to expose /etc/tags via your website.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. But is there any other API that we can use for the 'did you mean' functionality other than com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.Search api?

Comment: Search API is a specialised query engine so you can write your own if you want but normally it's down to oak index definitions with content tagging. I would recommend to open a new question so that wider community can answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are searching by using filter tags, You can Use TagManager Api to get all the resources tagged with some particular tag. 
ex : RangeIterator find(String basePath,
                             String[] tagIDs).

```
 basePath - The starting node of the search
 tagIDs - a list of tag IDs or full paths to tags
```

You can find lot more details here.
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/tagging/TagManager.html